# CSP Error when activating Google Analytics on a Community

Tags: community, google, google-analytics

I'm working on implementing **Google Analytics** tracking on one of our Community Sites.  I am following the instruction on [this guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_google_analytics_setup.htm&type=5).  I've currently completed steps 1-4 on the guide (which are basically the changes that are on the Salesforce side).

Before proceeding, I wanted to sanity check how it's going so far, but I've noticed that requests are not showing up on the Google Analytics side yet.  I'm also seeing a very strange CSP error (see below; note that I removed the **GA Id** for security reasons).  As you can see, I'm getting a CSP error for an image (image-src).  What is weird is that the image is being hosted on https://www.google.com.  I would have expected that image to be loaded from a different domain (like [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com)).

[image]

For further context, here are more of my settings.  Here is **Settings -> Advanced** (with GA Id removed).

[image]

And here are my **Settings -> Security & Privacy Settings**.
[image]

Am I supposed to create a new CSP entry to allow images from https://www.google.com?  If so, why don't the instructions mention it?

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this issue? After 24 hours did you start seeing Analytics? as from my experience this issue does not affect the gathering of analytics itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error, you need to add a CSP entry in **Setup** -> **CSP Trusted Sites**.

The entry should look like this:
[image]